# udp can't receive data sometimes

Tags: c#, udp

My udp client can't receive anything from server if no data was sent within 2 min before receiving.This is odd, if I call send, it can receive again. I ran the app in a simulator on windows,WireShark can catch all the packets,but my app can't detect it.I wonder if it is because the arp table is expired。

This only happens on mobiles devices and simulator,not on unity.

Anyone knows why?Thanks for answer.

udp client code:

```
    private UdpClient m_udpClient = null;
    private IPEndPoint m_IPEndPoint = null;
    public override bool Connect(string strIp, int nPort)
    {
        if (nPort == 0 || strIp.Length == 0)
        return false;

        if (m_udpClient == null || (m_udpClient.Client == null || !m_udpClient.Client.Connected))
        {
            m_udpClient = new UdpClient();
            try
            {
                m_udpClient.Connect(strIp, nPort);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                DebugLog.log("ex : " + ex.ToString());
            }

            if (m_udpClient.Client != null && m_udpClient.Client.Connected)
            {
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(strIp);
                m_IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, nPort);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}

private void receive()
{        
    while (m_udpClient.Client.Available > 0)
    {
        Byte[] data = null;
        try
        {
            data = m_udpClient.Receive(ref m_IPEndPoint);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                        DebugLog.log(e.ToString());
        }
        if (data != null && data.Length > 0)
        {               
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("receive,len:" + data.Length);
        }
    }
}

private void send(byte[] buf, int size)
{
    if (IsConnected())
    {
        try
        {
            m_udpClient.Send(buf, size);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DebugLog.log("ex : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public override bool IsConnected()
{
    return m_udpClient != null && m_udpClient.Client != null && m_udpClient.Client.Connected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question!
Between UDP server and client, we use "heartbeat-packet", has no problem.
when i stop "heartbeat-packet", After 15 seconds, server can't receive packet,
but wiresharp can catch all packet.

my network is simple, just PC direct connect device with wire.

by now, I had not found the true reason.
just repair it by repeat Send "empty-packet",  when "heartbeat-packet" is stoped.